# Sum range with indirect or whole row, what is faster?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, speed

In my Excel workbook I have a lot `sumif` or `sumproduct` formulas to sum ranges in other sheets. Those ranges are not fixed and always vary between 2000 to 10000 rows.

So, what is more efficient method for using those formulas, using dynamic range, whole columns or to use indirect function (when last row is known)? 
Also, for the future dilemmas, is there a way to calculate formula speed in Excel, let say in milliseconds?

Comment: There's a discussion of millisecond timers from 2010 in ExcelForum.com at [Using Milliseconds in VBA](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/738087-using-milliseconds-in-vba-print.html)

Comment: I don't have the canonical reference to hand but think when Excel 2007 (or possibly 2010) was released, whole column references were touted to be as fast as references to ranges due to changes in the calculation engine.  Also, `INDIRECT` and dynamic ranges are both Volatile in that they are always recalculated every time calculation is triggered.  They have a big overhead!

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I don't have to worry when using whole coluimn in formula and it's much easier to write it.

Comment: Regarding, VBA and millisecond discussion, I wouldn't know how to use it here.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Though SUMPRODUCT should not use full column references as it will actually iterate the ranges and many full column SUMPRODUCT will slow down the calculations.  Instead of INDIRECT or OFFSET, which has been pointed out are volatile, one can INDEX/MATCH, which is not volatile, to limit the range to only the data being used.